# Getting the first record got by orderBy clause using queryDSL

Tags: java, jpql, querydsl

I have a requirement to write a QueryDSL to fetch the lastest record in the table.To achieve this,i sort in descending order based on timeCreated and i am using singleResult to fetch the first record.

```
Object obj;
Object result = (Object) query.from(table)
    .where(CLAUSE)
    .orderBy(timeCreated.desc())
    .singleResult(obj);
```

I needed a clarification if the above(singleResult) would always fetch the first record in the sorted list(latest record)

Answer (score 0):

From the [querydsl 3 docs](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.1/apidocs/com/mysema/query/support/ProjectableQuery.html#singleResult(com.mysema.query.types.Expression...)) for `singleResult`:

> For multiple results only the first one is returned